# How to refer to Figures inside ffigbox?

Tags: captions, subfloats, floatrow

I have written the following code in which there are two figures and a table side by side. When I refer to the figure using `\ref{dev}` the reference shows up correctly but referring to the individual images `\ref{done}` and `\ref{dtwo}` does not show up.

```
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox[0.6\textwidth]{%
        \begin{subfloatrow}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]
          {\includegraphics[scale=0.34]{done.eps}}
          {\label{done}}
          {\caption{One}}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]
          {\includegraphics[scale=0.34]{dtwo.eps}}
          {\label{dtwo}}
          {\caption{Two}}
      \end{subfloatrow}
    %   \rule{1cm}{1cm}%
    }{%
      \caption{Figures}%
      {\label{dev}}
    }
    \capbtabbox[0.4\textwidth]{%
      \input{memorytable.tex}
    }{%
      \caption{Memory}%
      \label{mem}
    }
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Try adding the labels after `\caption`, e.g. `\ffigbox[0.6\textwidth]{%
        \begin{subfloatrow}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]
          {\includegraphics[scale=0.34]{done.eps}}
          {}
          {\caption{One}\label{done}}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]
          {\includegraphics[scale=0.34]{dtwo.eps}}
          {}
          {\caption{Two}\label{dtwo}}
      \end{subfloatrow}...`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Oh that worked.  I actually was adding a separate line as {\label{dtimeout}} after caption and that wasn't working